# Insert bulk data into two related tables with foreign keys from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have imported some data to a temp SQL table from an Excel file. Then I have tried to insert all rows to two related tables. Simply like this: There are Events and Actors tables with many to many relationship in my database. Actors are already added. I want to add all events to Events table and then add relation(ActorId) for each event to EventActors tables.
(dbo.TempTable has Title, ActorId columns)

```
insert into dbo.Event (Title) 
Select Title 
From dbo.TempTable

insert into dbo.EventActor (EventId, ActorId) 
Select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), ActorId                       --SCOPE_IDENTITY() is for EventId
From dbo.TempTable
```

When this code ran, all events inserted into Events, but the relations didn't inserted into EventActors because of Foreign Key error.

I think there should be a loop. But I am confused. I don't want to write C# code for this. I know there would be a simple but advanced solution trick for this in SQL Server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you insert your new Events you need to capture the new ids and write them back to the correct rows in your temp table so they are available for when you add your EventActors.

Comment: Thanks. I have figured it out in another way. But I want to learn how can i achieve this in Sql Server. Actually I understand the logic you advised, but I dont know how can I. I think there should be a loop: I will insert an event from the first row, then i will insert an eventactor for this event using the scope_identity. then go second line and do same until all rows finish. Is this true? Thanks again.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [output clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to capture the new IDs, with a [merge statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to allow capture from both source and destination tables.

Having captured this information, join it back to the temp table for the second insert.

Note you need a unique id per row, and this assumes 1 row in the temp table creates 1 row in both the Event and the EventActor tables.

```
-- Ensure every row has a unique id - could be part of the table create
ALTER TABLE dbo.TempTable ADD id INT IDENTITY(1,1);

-- Create table variable for storing the new IDs in
DECLARE @NewId TABLE (INT id, INT EventId);

-- Use Merge to Insert with Output to allow us to access all tables involves
-- As Insert with Output only allows access to columns in the destination table
MERGE INTO dbo.[Event] AS Target
USING dbo.TempTable AS Source
ON 1 = 0 -- Force an insert regardless
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Title)
    VALUES (Source.Title)
    OUTPUT Source.id, Inserted.EventId
    INTO @NewId (id, EventId);

-- Insert using new Ids just created
INSERT INTO dbo.EventActor (EventId, ActorId) 
    SELECT I.EventId, T.ActorId
    FROM dbo.TempTable T
    INNER JOIN @NewId I on T.id = T.id;
```