# Copy multiple rows of same table but with different id and store old ids of copied row in column name old ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code using curser it doing well but I don't want to use cursers due to speed issues

```
DECLARE @StudentID NVARCHAR(MAX)='1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'    

SELECT value StudentID INTO #TMP_tbSchedulTas FROM STRING_SPLIT(@StudentID,',')

DECLARE @SchedID AS Integer
SELECT @SchedID = StudentID
FROM #TMP_tbSchedulTas

DECLARE Attendence CURSOR FOR

SELECT StudentID FROM #TMP_tbSchedulTas

OPEN Attendence
FETCH NEXT FROM Attendence INTO @SchedID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Student
(
FirstName,LastName,
FatherName,DOB,CNIC,Religon,Mobile,Email,Address,Gender,Isactive,Isdeleted,CreatedBy,CreatedOn,CityID,OldstudentId,BranchID,IsSelected,StudentGUID )
SELECT FirstName,LastName,
FatherName,DOB,CNIC,Religon,Mobile,Email,Address,Gender,Isactive,Isdeleted,CreatedBy,CreatedOn,CityID,@SchedID,BranchID,IsSelected,StudentGUID FROM dbo.Student
WHERE StudentID=@SchedID

FETCH NEXT FROM Attendence INTO @SchedID
END

CLOSE Attendence
DEALLOCATE Attendence

-- drop temporary table to store schedule event attendees email status
DROP TABLE #TMP_tbSchedulTas
```

Comment: Use the [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [`merge` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64458865/1127428)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it like so, however I'm not sure if you really want to read from the same table and insert into it again for which reason!

```
DECLARE @StudentID NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10';

INSERT INTO dbo.Student
    (
        FirstName
        , LastName
        , FatherName
        , DOB
        , CNIC
        , Religon
        , Mobile
        , Email
        , Address
        , Gender
        , Isactive
        , Isdeleted
        , CreatedBy
        , CreatedOn
        , CityID
        , OldstudentId
        , BranchID
        , IsSelected
        , StudentGUID
    )
SELECT
    FirstName
    , LastName
    , FatherName
    , DOB
    , CNIC
    , Religon
    , Mobile
    , Email
    , Address
    , Gender
    , Isactive
    , Isdeleted
    , CreatedBy
    , CreatedOn
    , CityID
    , @SchedID
    , BranchID
    , IsSelected
    , StudentGUID
FROM
    dbo.Student
WHERE
    StudentID IN
        (
            SELECT
                value StudentID
            FROM
                STRING_SPLIT(@StudentID, ',')
        );
```

Comment: I think instead of using @SchedID i can user direct studentID